# Awk command to cut the url

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I want to cut my url https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/ into https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com I have tried several ways to handle it

```
$ echo https://jenkins-crumbtest2-test.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/ | cut -d"/" -f3 | cut -d"/" -f5
jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com
```

I have 3 inputs which i want to pass to get the expected output. I want to pass any of the input to get the same output.

Input:

```
1. https://jenkins-crumbtest2-test.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/ (or) 
2. https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/ (or)
3. https://jenkins-crumbtest2-test-lite.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/
```

Expected Output:

```
https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: This is not clear at all.You should always 3 simple things in your question. 1- Sample of input in CODE TAGS, 2- sample of expected in CODE TAGS, 3- Your efforts which you have put to solve your own problem, please do add all by editing your question and let us know then.

Comment: So, you want to remove the subdomain part from the URL and return only the domain part ???

Comment: san & ravi, Thanks for responding. I have 3 inputs which i had posted. If the user passes any type of input it would result to expected output. (https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com)

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, Request you to please EDIT your post and wrap/cover your SAMPLES/CODES into CODE TAGS for better understanding of your question,kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: Ravi, Updated the query as you suggested. Please do needful.

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, Thanks. So is your url `origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com` fixed for all links? If not then which part should be captured and which part should be ignored? Please do let us know rules for getting the sample expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hi Ravi, The URL is fixed for all sample inputs. If user pass any-type of input url it should convert to expected output. 'Expected O/P: https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com'

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, Sorry not sure still not able to get it completely,please explain it more.

Comment: I want to cut the url with help of awk/cut commands https://jenkins-crumbtest2-test.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/  into  https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com  likewise for   https://jenkins-crumbtest2-test-lite.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/   into expected output. Can i have one command to handle all input scenarios with awk command.

Comment: Ex: echo  https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com | awk '{sub(/jenkins-[^.]*\./,"");sub(/\/$/,":443")} 1'  Got output : https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443

Comment: What is the output if the input is `test.google.com`?

Comment: `awk '{ print "https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com" }' `

Comment: @Luuk Without having read the comments I was just going to give that exact answer :)

Comment: Why do you want to use awk for this, sed is a more obvious choice for anything that's a simple s/old/new/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '{gsub(/:\/\/.*test\.|:\/\/.*crumbtest2\.|:\/\/.*test-lite\./,"://")} 1' Input_file
```

OR non-one liner form of solution above is as follows.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/:\/\/.*test\.|:\/\/.*crumbtest2\.|:\/\/.*test-lite\./,"://")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  gsub(/:\/\/.*test\.|:\/\/.*crumbtest2\.|:\/\/.*test-lite\./,"://")     ##Gobally substituting everything till test OR crumbtest OR test-lite with :// in line.
}
1                                                                        ##Printing current line here.
'  Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file name h
```

Answer (score 2):

This awk skips the records that don't have fixed string `origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com` in them:

```
awk 'match($0,/origin-ctc-core-nonprod\.com/){print "https://" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

You can use it with: `echo`*`string`*`| awk ...`, `cat`*`file`*`|`or `awk ...`*`file`* .

Explined:

```
awk '                                           # using awk
match($0,/origin-ctc-core-nonprod\.com/) {      # if fixed string is matched
    print "https://" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # output https:// and fixed string
    # exit                                      # uncomment if you want only 
}'                                              # one line of output like in sample
```

Or if you don't need the `https://` part, you could just use `grep`:

```
grep -om 1 "origin-ctc-core-nonprod\.com"
```

Then again:

```
$ var=$(grep -om 1 "origin-ctc-core-nonprod\.com" file) && echo https://$var
```

Comment: Op said: " If the user passes any type of input it would result to expected output. (origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com)" ....This is not doing that 

Comment: My initial answer was: `while IFS='$\n' read -r line; do echo "https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com" ; done` :D